# Download themes and extension using magento connect error occured

Tags: magento-1.9

When i try to download extension or themes using magento connect i got an error:

```
Could not resolve host:magento-community.
```

Can anyone suggest for this?

Comment: Can you please specify it with screen shot?

Comment: Better than a screenshot, could you copy and paste in the information: what command are you using for downloading an extension or theme, and what is the full error message?